# How to turn an array into an object with two values? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to put an array into an object with two keys (key, val). This is my code.

```
var arr = ["hello", "44", "thanks", "32"];

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj.key = arr[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

this is the result i would like to have.

```
obj[0] = {key: "hello", val: "44"}; 
obj[1] = {key: "thanks", val: "32"};
```

Thanks allot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you want is a loop every 2 item instead of 1, and then take the current item and the next one.

Maybe something like this :

```
obj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i=i+2) {
  obj.push({key:arr[i], val:arr[i+1]});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try underscorejs

http://underscorejs.org/#object

Comment: This should better be a comment instead of answer